Как создать правильную структуру Django-проекта, а также отобразить html (наследуемый) + CSS?

Меня также интересует, что прописать в:
urls, settings, views.
views.py
    from django.shortcuts import render
    
    
    def func(request):
        return render(request, 'base.html')

urls.py
    from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls'))
    ]

base.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}My Site{% endblock %}</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </main>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; My Site 2024</p>
    </footer>

    <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>

secord.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="vertical-blocks">
        <div class="block-A">Вертикальный блок A</div>
        <div class="block-B">Вертикальный блок B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal-blocks">
        <div class="block-C">Горизонтальный блок C</div>
        <div class="block-D">Горизонтальный блок D</div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

как сделать чтоб исчезла ошибка?
PS C:\Users\d_mur\Desktop\django\hotels> python manage.py runserver 
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1010, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\Desktop\django\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper 
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\Desktop\django\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 133, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\Desktop\django\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 486, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\Desktop\django\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\Desktop\django\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\Desktop\django\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\Desktop\django\env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 519, in check    
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\Desktop\django\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 47, in __get__ 
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\Desktop\django\env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 738, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\Desktop\django\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 47, in __get__ 
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\Desktop\django\env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 731, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\Desktop\django\hotels\Hotels\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    path('', include('myapp.urls'))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\Desktop\django\env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 39, in include        
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\d_mur\Desktop\django\hotels\myapp\urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    path('', include('myapp.urls'))
             ^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'include' is not defined

в папке Hotels код файла urls.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls'))
]


Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
